# How can i get surname from paragraph element

Tags: javascript

How can i get only the surname from `<p>` tag with JS, i already trued bu my code is incorrect, how can i do it properly?

```
<p class="surname">Janet Garcia</p>

var surname = document.getElementsByClassName("surname")[0].lastElementChild.innerHTML;
console.log(surname);
```

Comment: What happens if you have `<p class="surname">Firstname Middlename Surname</p>` or even 2 surnames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the class name being wrong, which I assume is a simple typo, the correct way to get an element's text content is, surprisingly enough, `.textContent`.

```
var name = document.getElementsByClassName("surname")[0].textContent;
console.log(name); // "Janet Garcia"
```

From there, you can split the name into parts:

```
var nameparts = name.split(" ");
var surname = nameparts.pop(); // get the last one
console.log(surname); // "Garcia"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var surnameParagraph = document.querySelectorAll("p.surname")[0];
var name = surnameParagraph.textContent;

var spaceIdx = name.indexOf(" ");

var firstName = name.substring( 0, spaceIdx );
var lastName  = name.substring( spaceIdx + 1 );

console.log( lastName );
```

Answer (score -1):

I would split the string by spaces, then return the last element from the split array. On second thought I would just pop it off the end of the array.

```js
var name = document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerText,
    surname = name.split(' ').pop();

console.log( surname );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<p class="name">Janet Garcia</p>
```

Comment: Note that `innerText` is the "old Internet Explorer" way of doing it and hasn't been valid since IE9. Use `textContent` instead.